# How to correctly use sockets over the internet in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

my Sockets are correctly working in my local network, but when sending the program to a friend, he cant connect to me.

I host the server with this Code:

```
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 30000));
listener.Listen(500);
```

And he connects to this server using my external IP address (gotten from http://whatismyip.org/) and my specified port (30000) with this code:

```
Socket inOut = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
inOut.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox5.Text), 30000));
```

When using cmd netstat -a i cant find a listening entry with port 30000, so i guess that my server has the wrong settings or i need to specify something different, but i already opened the port in my router (30000).

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but doesnt take the method .Listen(int Port) as argument? Which means you listen on port 500?

Comment: the number is the backlog, which specifies the number of possible connections

Comment: @Loading more accurately, it is the max number of connections that can be queued waiting to be accepted by the server calling `Socket.(Begin)Accept()`. It is not the max number of accepted connections that the server can work with at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As-is, the code you have shown *should* work, IF all of these conditions are met:

- **your ISP has assigned your Internet connection an IPv6 address**. Ask your ISP. Many ISPs don't do this yet for home users. If your ISP has not, your client will have to use `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` (IPv4) instead.  Depending on what kind of IP your client wants to connect to, it needs to create an appropriate `Socket` type. An IPv4 socket can't connect to an IPv6 IP address, and an IPv6 socket can't connect to an IPv4 address (unless it is configured to be a [dual-stack socket](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/01/08/dual-mode-sockets-never-create-an-ipv4-socket-again/)).
- **your ISP is not blocking inbound TCP connections to your Internet IP**. Many ISPs do, so they can charge customers extra for hosting their own servers.  Most home Internet users don't need to run their own servers. Ask your ISP if this feature is enabled for your Internet account.
- **your router is configured to forward inbound packets** received by the router's public IP address on port 30000 to your server's LAN IPv6 address on port 30000.  If your router does not have a public IPv6 address (because the ISP hasn't assigned one), you will have to use `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` on the client side. Because a router is sitting between the client and server, they can use different IP versions to communicate with the router.
- **your server code is calling `listener.Accept()` or `Listener. BeginAccept()`** after `listener.Listen()` exits without error.  This is a given if your code already works on the local LAN, but I'm throwing it in anyway for good measure.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` instead of `AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6`